# Evaluate $\int_0^t e^{-\lambda s} \,\text{erf}(\ln(t-s))\,\text{d}s$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, convolution, error-function

I'm trying to efficiently graph the function $I(t)$ for $t>0$ where

$$I(t) :=\int_0^t e^{-\lambda s} \,\text{erf}(\ln(t-s))\,\text{d}s,\qquad \lambda>0$$

but its evaluation is beyond my powers of integration. I can use a numerical integration package to plot it, but it is pretty slow. Happy to compute a decent approximation if it's available.

Mathematica was not able to provide an answer, and I've tried some integral substitutions like $u=\ln(t-s)$, as well as looked through the fantastic [table of erf integrals](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73b/jresv73bn1p1_a1b.pdf), but no solution seems to be clear.

My current strategy is to approximate the exponential by a quartic polynomial $$\exp(-\lambda x)\approx \sum_{k=0}^4 c_k (\lambda x)^k$$
in some region $x\in[0,R]$, and set to zero when $x>R$. Then I *can* compute $\int s^k \text{erf}(\ln(t-s))\,\text{d}s$, but there are a painful number of terms when using a quartic - are there any better suggestions? Perhaps some other approximation of the $\exp$, or nice series expansion of the function?

Thanks!

**Edit**: Just to be clear, imagine I am given ten thousand different values of $\lambda$, and I want to graph $I(t)$ for each of them in the region $t\in [0,100]$. How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: Are you seeking an approximation for small $t$ (like $[0,1]$) or an asymptotic as $t\to\infty$?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I'm looking to graph $I(t)$, so I need to compute it at a range of values of $t$. Though because the integrand has an $\exp(-\lambda s)$ in the front, it should converge relatively quickly, so its probably fine to consider $t\in [0, 5/\lambda]$, hence my attempt at using a polynomial spline in some small region.
Note that $\lambda$ could be big or small.

Comment: We can write the integral as the solution of the ODE $I'(t)+\lambda I(t)=\operatorname{erf}\log t$ with initial value $I(0)=0$. I conjecture that there exists a unique argmin $t_\lambda\in(0,1)$ such that $I'(t)<0$ for all $0<t<t_\lambda$ and $I'(t)>0$ for all $t>t_\lambda$. In addition, it is not difficult to prove that $I(+\infty)=1/\lambda$ using the theory of Laplace transforms.

Comment: The SageMath code `var('x,y');ell=4;plot_slope_field(-ell*y+erf(log(x)),(x,0,5),(y,-0.4,0.5))` generates the slope field of the DE where our desired function (easily identifiable from the plot) has slopes tending to zero. [Snippet](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwrSyzSUK_QqVTXtE7NybE1sS7IyS-JL87JL0iNT8tMzUnR0AWKa1VqpxalaeTkp2tUaGrqKGhU6BjomIIYlTq6BnomOgZ6ppqaAMB7FoI=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Thanks for the snippet. I've never used SageMath before, looks neat.

Comment: I've made an edit to my question to clarify my problem, in case it helps.

Comment: Try $u=t-x$ to get rid of the $t$ in the $\text{erf}(\ln(t-s))$

Comment: Also try a series solution for $$y’+\lambda y-\text{erf}(\ln t)=0$$ as a user said above